# Find the lines that are most deep (right intended) for a group of lines in a file Unix/Linux

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk, grep

I have a file that contains data in the following pattern:

Input:

```
C#
Visual Basic
    Basic
        Algol
            BPCL
                Assembly
        PL1
            BPCL1
        PL2
Java
    Spring
    Groovy
Ruby
R
C++
    C
        B
            Fortran
                Assembly1
Python
    Perl
```

Required Output:

```
C#
Assembly
BPCL1
PL2
Spring
Groovy
Ruby
R
Assembly1
Perl
```

For each group of lines (lines are grouped by indentation i.e.  if the indentation of the next line is unchanged or relatively right to the previous one, they form one group, and, if the next line is intended relatively left to the previous one, it forms a new group. Lines that do not have spaces in the beginning, by default, form a new group ), I want to find the line which is most right intended.

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: It's unclear what the criterion for skipping unindented lines is.

Comment: @BenjaminW. IMHO unindented lines are skipped when followed by indented lines. An unindented line without children is the most deep one in his own group of 1 line.

Comment: @WalterA Ah, makes sense!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Every time a line doesn't start with an indent, print the deepest line of the previous group (and also after the last line).

```
awk '!/^ / && deepest {print deepest;last_offset=0}
                {offset=match($0, "[^ ]")}
     offset==last_offset {deepest=deepest RS  substr($0,offset)}
     offset>last_offset  {last_offset=offset; deepest=substr($0,offset)}
     END {print deepest}' inputfile
```

Explanation:

`!/^ / && deepest` Line that does not start with a space and deepest not yet set.
(an alternative for `deepest` was NR>1)
`{print deepest;last_offset=0}` print deepest line from last block and reset offset
`{offset=match($0, "[^ ]")}` Look for first non-space character and remember offset.
`offset==last_offset` Special case: 2 lines with the same depth
`{deepest=deepest RS  substr($0,offset)}` append current line to last line
`offset>last_offset` line deeper than remembered one
`{last_offset=offset; deepest=substr($0,offset)}` store offset and line without indent
`END {print deepest}` also print deepest line in last block

Comment: The above solution worked for the original requirement. I have modified my requirement a bit and I have now explained the line grouping criteria in more detail. Could you please help me with that ?

Comment: @NayanShirbhate Changing a question should be avoided. Perhaps accept this answer for the original question, and modify above script for the new requirements. When stuck, you can post your efforts and show what is wrong with the output that you get. And think about a clear description of your question. Maybe something like: `Whenever a line has the same or more indention than the next line, print that line`. With this description you can get some inspiration in how to solve this (remember last indent en last line and print it when you are processing a new line with less indention).

Comment: Hard to write a requirement. `Whenever a line has the same or more indention than the next line, print that line` is not complete: `, but only when it has the same or more indention than the previous line.` (and something about first/last line).

Comment: Can't we just say `Print a line only if the the indentation of the next line is equal to or less than that of the current line, and, print the last line of the file by default.`

Comment: How about `PL2` ? Your rule prints it.

Comment: I need PL2. I guess you missed the required output section.

Comment: Than your requirement is OK.